# Can Alexa Skills have a list and a phrase slot?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

Is it possible to have an intent that has a list and an phrase (or two lists but the other is dynamically created)? Here's an example utterance I was hoping to make:

*How many {foodstuff} does {someone} have?*

- {foodstuff} could be a list of [cookies, doughnuts, lollipops]
- {someone} would be an arbitrary text or a very big list (think contents of a database column)

I realize this can be achieved using a multiple turn dialogue, but can it be done in one phrase?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create slot for Foodstuff/someone and have to be populated with all the possible values that you can expect in those slot.

Comment: Thank you. That’s a bit discouraging.